# How do I split a numpy array into to subarrays based on a list of indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of indices and need to split a numpy array into two subarrays based on it. One subarray will be the elements located at the indices, the other will be the remaining elements. Can anybody recommend an appropriate way to do it using index notation.

Here is an example

```py
a = np.arange(10)
idx = np.random.choice(10, 3, replace=False)
```

With these arrays, I want to select the three randomly chosen elements from `a` as well as the remaining elements. The expression `a[idx]` of course gives the first part, but `a[~idx]` isn't right. There has to be a way to convert the array `idx` into its complement, right?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a mask to select the elements, then invert the mask to select the complement:

```py
a = np.arange(10)

idx = np.random.choice(10, 3, replace=False)
mask = np.zeros_like(a, dtype=bool)
mask[idx] = True

selected = a[mask]
unselected = a[~mask]
```

Sample output:

```
>>> selected
array([1, 3, 5])
>>> unselected
array([0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sets` operation:

```
a = np.arange(10)
idx1 = np.random.choice(10, 3, replace=False)
idx2 = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(len(a)), idx1)

# Same as:
# idx2 = list(set(range(10)).difference(idx1))
```

Output:

```
>>> a[idx1]
array([2, 4, 8])

>>> a[idx2]
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
all = np.arange(np.size(a))
m = (idx[:, None] == all).any(axis=0)
a[m], a[~m]
```